# How can I fix a group policy error running NPM RUN scripts on Windows 10

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, npm-scripts, group-policy

I'm receiving the following group policy error when I try to run NPM scripts in my project:

```
PS C:\Users\reir8p\code\whiteboard\frontend> npm run start

> whiteboard@0.0.0 start
> ng serve

This program is blocked by group policy. For more information, contact your system administrator.
```

If I execute the command directly, I do not receive any errors.

```
PS C:\Users\reir8p\code\whiteboard\frontend> ng serve

\ Generating browser application bundles... {works as expected}
```

The relevant lines of my package.json file is:

```json
{
  "name": "whiteboard",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
     "start": "ng serve",
  },
  ...
```

I am able to successfully execute `> npm run start` from "Windows PowerShell" as an administrator. I haven't been able to find any relevant sections in my Windows security policies.

I get the same error with other NPM scripts as well. I also received a similar "This program is blocked..." error when trying to install Anaconda, which I think might be related.

Has anyone else received a similar error or know where I should look to troubleshoot? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In our case Applocker blocked the execution.

Please check the Windows Eventlog (Event viewer/Applications and Services Logs/Microsoft/Windows/AppLocker/MSI and Scripts).

Answer (score 0):

As per @Suede1997's recommendation, Fixed this by updating the AppLocker security policies. Local Security Policy/Application Control Policies/AppLocker/Script Rules --> Remove restriction for "Everyone" (mine was set to allow "All Files located in the Program Files folder" and allow "All files located in the Windows folder".

Event Viewer was helpful to identify when the scripts were being blocked.

Answer (score 0):

We were able to overcome this by looking at batch file and decoding what it would have run, so in our case `npm start` became:

```json
"start": "node node_modules\\react-scripts\\scripts\\start",
```